# How to set up indirect dependency with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I was using cocoaPods to manage 3rd party libraries,and original target of project therefore depends on cocoaPods.Then I added another target, which depends on the original one.
But the weird thing is when I build the second target, there was an error saying  the target cannot find some of .h files under the management of cocoaPods.Has anyone seen this before?what's the solution,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed there is a choice in Podfile:

```
link_with ['MyApp', 'MyOtherApp']
```

this would let multiple targets depend on cocoaPods,and it worked.